# Trying to export PDF from html with hebrew charactars

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to export the table to PDF file but if there are Hebrew characters it wont display them correctry.

I've tried to add mata tag of UTF-8 in the HEAD section and also with php header of 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'

```
function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

    source = $('#customers')[0];

    specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 10,
        width: 300
    };
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    }, margins);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting HTML of a specific element to a PDF file, this HTML is not containing any header information, so you should add this information before you export it to pdf. Here you can see an example how to add the utf-8 information.

```
pdf.fromHTML(
    '<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><body>' + source + '</body></html',
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    }
    ...
);
```

Comment: Not working... The PDF shows: "[object HTMLDivElement]"

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use dir="rtl" for more info please go through this below link

https://developers.itextpdf.com/ja/node/2079

Comment: The issue is that the Hebrew turns to:  "é Þ è Ù ê   Õ Ù Õ à Ù   á Ñ Ò   ( 4 )"